# Derivative product

Tags: limits, derivatives

I was going through the list of derivative rules and it occurred to me that I didn't see any of the form $C(f,g)$ where $C$ is a function of functions $f,g$ and $C' = f'\cdot g' + \cdots$ where $'$ denotes the derivative. The derivatives $f',g'$ were always in separate terms in a sum.

Is there such a form possible and if not, what's the reason for that?

Edit: In light of comments by mrf below, I'd add the additional stipulation that $f,g$ be "black boxes" to $C$. So even given an evaluation of $f,g$ at some point $x$, one should be able to also evaluate $C(f(x), g(x))$ without knowing the formula for $f,g$. Note that this only puts a restriction on $C$, not for evaluating $C'$ (for which you'd in most cases need to know the forms of $f,g$)

Answer (score 1):

Does:
$$
f'g' = (fg')' - fg''
$$
count? (This is integration by parts, in a thin disguise.)

Comment: What would be corresponding function C in this case that would generate the r.h.s as a derivative?

Comment: That's why I asked if you think it counts. $C(f,g) = (fg')'-fg''$. Even though it looks like the right hand side doesn't "just depend" on $f$ and $g$, it really does. (Since derivatives of $f$ and $g$ are determinded by the functions.) [Oh, now I saw the prime in the $C'$. In that case it probably doesn't count. You need to take $C(f,g)$ as an antiderivative of $(fg')'-fg''$, and this is sorta still a function of $f$ and $g$.]

Comment: So I don't really care about additional terms so the $-fg''$ doesn't matter to me. So technically, I suppose you could define $C(f,g) = fg'$ and thus get $f'g'$ in the r.h.s but yeah, this isn't really what I had in mind -- though I'm not sure of a good way to exclude it.

Comment: Questions like these are almost always impossible to formulate to reflect exactly what you had in mind!

Comment: I guess what I meant was that $f,g$ are black boxes to $C$. So given evaluations of $f,g$ at some $x$, one should be able to compute $C$.

Comment: The problem with that formulation is that the derivative of a function at a point is *not* determined by the value of the function itself at just that point.

Comment: But that should be ok right? As that'd definitely exclude $C$ taking the derivative of either $f$ or $g$. It could only use the value of $f,g$. So only basically "plug them in" into a formula

Comment: Yes, but with that restriction, you can't get *any* formula depending on the derivatives on the other side of the equality either: $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$ doesn't satisfy your restrictions now.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. $C(f,g) = fg$. So $C$ can be evaluated using only values for $f,g$. Evaluation for $C'$ requires knowing the forms of $f,g$ but there are no restrictions on $C'$, only on $C$.

Comment: Sorry, I keep forgetting about that prime on your $C$.

Answer (score 0):

One answer is that the units wouldn't match up.

If the units for $f$ and $g$ are meters, and the variable $x$ is in terms of minutes, then any combination of $f$ and $g$ that has units would have meters, meters$^2$, meters$^3$, etc. The derivative would have units meters(something) per minute.

The same thing would apply for $f'$ and $g'$: Their units would be something involving meters, per minute, so their product would have units being something involving meters per minute squared.

There is no way to make meters(something) per minute be the same unit as meters(something) per minute squared. Hence, no formula would make sense, from that point of view.

Comment: True I suppose in the context of physics, but I was looking for a more mathematical answer